# Why doesn't this call to .Result provoke a deadlock?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, async-await

I'm still trying to wrap my head around when I can use .Result, and when I can't. I have been trying to avoid it entirely, by using async "all the way down".

While doing some work in our **ASP.NET** web app (NOT core), I came across this code. Now, the code works (and has been working for 2 years), so I know it works, I just don't know why it works.

This is fired from a sync controller method. It is a chain of method calls that goes through a few layers until it finally does some HTTP work. I have simplified the code here:

```
// Class1
public byte[] GetDocument1(string url)
{
    return class2.GetDocument2(url).Result;
}

// Class2
public Task<byte[]> GetDocument2(string url)
{
    return class3.GetDocument3(url)
}

// Class3
public async Task<byte[]> GetDocument3(string url)
{
    var client = GetHttpClient(url);
    var resp = client.GetAsync(url).Result;

    if(resp.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        using(var httpStream = await resp.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
        {
            // we are also using
            await httpStream.ReadAsync(...);
        }
    }
}
```

So as far as I can tell, when this all starts, I'm on the "main ASP sync context" (I start in a controller and eventually get to this code). We aren't using any `.ConfigureAwait(false)`, so I believe we are always returning to this context.

1. In `GetDocument3`, why doesn't `client.GetAsync(url).Result` deadlock?
2. `GetDocument3` is mixing `.Result` with `await` stuff. In general, is that a good idea?? Is it OK here because `.Result` comes before the awaits?
3. In `GetDocument1`, why doesn't `.Result` deadlock?

Comment: `I'm still trying to wrap my head around when I can use .Result` why? Why not just follow the advice: don't use it.

Comment: @mason - c'mon man, you know that's just not always possible. In addition, I HATE not knowing stuff. .Result is real, and apparently legit, and I feel I should know how/when to use it.

Comment: What do you mean "not always possible"? If you aren't in an async context, don't try to use async code. Which means you should always be able to `await` and should never need to use `.Result`. If you want to know when to use it, the answer is "never".

Comment: If the code you're invoking doesn't rely on the synchronization context, than it will not deadlock.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`client.GetAsync(url).Result` is synchronously blocking. `resp.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync()` is actually not doing any awaiting. The `Task` is already completed, because `HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead` is used in `GetAsync`, so the entire block of code here is synchronous code pretending to be asynchronous.

In general, you should never use `.Result` or `.Wait` or `Task.Wait*` - if you absolutely have to, use `GetAwaiter().GetResult()`, which doesn't throw exceptions wrapped in `AggregateException`s, for which you may not have a `catch`, but even that should be avoided like the plague. You're right to use `async` all the way down.

The deadlock is only a problem in a context that wants to return back to the original thread (e.g. UI or ASP.NET), and that thread is blocked by a synchronous wait. If you always use `ConfigureAwait(false)` on *every* `await`, *unless* you know you actually need to preserve the context on the continuation (usually only at the top level UI event handler because you need to update something on the UI, or in the top level of the ASP.NET controller) then you should be safe.

Synchronous blocking inside asynchronous code also isn't good, but won't cause the deadlock. Using `await` with `ConfigureAwait(true)` (the default), inside a synchronous wait, in a context that wants to return back to a specific thread will cause the deadlock.

Comment: @georgeHeylar - re: 3rd paragraph. Ok but, I'm in ASP.NET. I'm still on that original context/thread. I am synchronously blocking on that `GetAsync().Result`, right? So if I'm blocking, and `GetAsync()` is going to continue on that blocked thread ... how does that work? Is it "ok" to use `.Result` BECAUSE `GetAsync()` is guaranteed to run on some other thread, or something like that?

Comment: Actually, `GetAwaiter().GetResult()` unwraps the `AggregateException`.

Comment: When you use `.Result`, it executes synchronously, blocking the thread and never leaving it, so it has no problem getting back on that thread because it never left. If you were using `.Result` on an outer `Task` and an `await` with `.ConfigureAwait(true)` on the inner `Task` in asp.net, the inner wouldn't be able to return to the thread that was currently blocking on the outer `Task`. Thanks Paulo, I didn't know that! Just not getting an unexpected `AggregateException` that probably has no `catch` is really what I care about when using it.